# How to play .mkv video in ASP.NET MVC using Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, mkv

THis is a Self explantory title!
I have a asp.net mvc application where I display videos from youtube. Now we decided not to use youtube because of their ads and other... First I used

```
     @Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video.Flash(...)
```

to display `.swf` videos. Can anyone tell me How to play `.mkv` videos in ASP.NET MVC using(or not using) `Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video` helper ?